# Possible to publish wagtail pages to s3 bucket?

Tags: wagtail

wagtail-bakery looks like it lets you publish the whole site to an s3 bucket.

Is there a way to publish individual pages to an s3 bucket when the user hits "publish" in the page editor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter, see https://github.com/tomdyson/wagtail-netlify/blob/master/wagtailnetlify/models.py#L17-L35 from my wagtail-netlify app, which runs the equivalent of `./manage.py build` (for the whole site) on page publish.